# Domain Joined computer doesn't browser properly with any website with Let's Encrypt CA cert

Tags: tls, web-browser, firefox, browser-extensions, letsencrypt

Navigating to any website with Let's Encrypt CA cert and even after enabling the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS_Everywhere) addon,

I'm getting *"Your connection is not private"*.
Getting this error from all the browser except Firefox

The certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification authority

This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

[image]

Presently my system was Domain Joined computer and not connected to that particular Domain

Solved by Importing *.pem files from Let's Encrypt CA cert to Microsoft Management Console (MMC)

- https://letsencrypt.org/certs/trustid-x3-root.pem.txt
- https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt
- https://letsencrypt.org/certs/letsencryptauthorityx3.pem.txt

After importing, now able to browse any website with Let's Encrypt CA cert without any warnings to HTTPS websites

Why would website based on Let's Encrypt CA cert doesn't browse with HTTPS. But rest of the SSL based websites browse perfectly

Comment: Firefox uses their own certificates to store. It doesn't depend upon system certificates. That's the reason i'm able to browse after reinstalling, updating also @Ahmad

Comment: Not much is known about your system. But obviously the Let's Encrypt CA was not inside the OS trust store. This might be for example because the system is too old (nothing known about that) or because there was some corporate policy which removed the certificate from the trust store. Or it might be just something went wrong, i.e. unintended consequence of some change to the system (nothing known about it either).